# "Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce `img` tags as an image." Code ERROR

Tags: reactjs, compiler-warnings

I typed `<img src= {'https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300'}alt="photo" />` on my React js file,
after I saved the file and I got an error message on GitBash saying ,

`Redundant alt attribute. Screen-readers already announce 'img' tags as an image. You don’t need to use the words 'image', 'photo,' or 'picture' (or any specified custom words) in the alt prop  jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt`

Then I removed the `alt` from the code, and I got the error message saying,

`img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is not a Git issue and not a bash issue. The error message itself seems clear enough though: you must supply an "alt" property and it must not read "photo". Write a *description of the contents of the image* as the alternate text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this one and it worked:

`<input type="image" img src = {'https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300'} alt="photo" />`

(I have used `` not the single quotation marks for the url)

Answer (score 10):

<img src= {'https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300'}alt="something" />

'something' diffrent from the words 'photo' and 'image' (or any specified custom words).

Comment: Even if the alt text contains "image" or "photo" you may still get the error.  Ex: I changed "repeated image" changed to "repeated thing"

Answer (score 5):

I have same error issues in my react app. You can try this following codes.

---

❌ not work

```
<img src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300`} alt="photo" />
```

It's also not work.

```
<img src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300`} alt="Photo by John Doe" />
```

Don't use alt that contain keywords : `photo`, `image`, or `picture`.

---

✅ work

For example: (change alt tag with some image description without keyword)

```
<img src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300`} alt="cutest kitten" />
```

---

Maybe, empty alt is alternative option.

✅ work

```
<img src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300`} alt="" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

it's actually saying that inside your alt you don't need to use words like **image**, **photo**, or **picture**.

Example:

instead of

```html
<img src="#" alt="photo"/>
```

try this :

```html
<img src="#" alt="souvenir"/>
```

I put souvenir as an alt but you can choose any others words that describe well your image

Answer (score 0):

Declare one keyword  like

```
let alText = 'photo'
```

and use

```
<img src= {'https://robohash.org/${id}?size=300x300'} alt={alText} />
```

Answer (score 0):

From this to

```html
<img className="card-img" src={'https://www.shutterstock.com/'} alt="Card image" />
```

This->

```html
<img className="card-img" src={'https://www.shutterstock.com/'} alt="" />
```

**Here we have to change the alt tag value other than image, photo or picture**